# how to make rating form in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to make a rating form in iPhone. I am using sqlite manager. If a user clicks the rating form(stars) the rating will be stored in a database. I dont have any idea how to store the rating(stars) in the database. Please give me any idea how to store rating(stars) in a database.

I am following [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view) how to develop stars rating. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store it as a integer value. Eg. If 2 star save 2 in database.
2. If you .5 rating also then save it as float. Eg. If 2 and half start then save 2.5 in database.
3. Depending upon the value draw your stars.

Answer (score 1):

Giving ratings is nothing but the magic of images. Here's the logic for this..

Follow the steps explained below:

**1.** Prepare 3 images for each star
       **1.1** Unselected star (Gray Star)
       **1.2** Half Star (Half Gray/Yellow star)
       **1.3** Full Star (Yellow star)

**2.** Initially all 5 stars are fully gray & db value for ratings field is 0

**3**. Now prepare condition,
      **3.1** if User clicks one time then it receives half star, the image is changed from gray to half gray & the database value will be changed from 0 to 0.5 
      **3.2** if User clicks again then the image will be changed from half gray to fully green & the database value will be changed from 0.5 to 1.0

1. Now if user clicks the green star
     **4.1** the image will be changed from 1.0 to 0.5 and, the ratings field in database will be from 1.0 to 0.5 
   **4.2** if user clicks again the half gray star then the value in the db will be changed from 0.5 to 0 & the image will be fully gray star.

Enjoy Programming !